# Threads en JFrame

Tags: java, hilos

Necesito hacer un Reloj Digital, pero para ello es necesario crear una clase main y un JFrame, en el cual tengo que heredar la clase Thread, y no implementar Runnable.

Alguien me puede decir como heredar el Thread en el JFrame?

Comment: Bueno, solo puedes extender a una clase, asi que creo que podrias crear una clase que extienda de Thread y que contenga un JFrame o al reves, que extienda de JFrame y que contenga un Thread dentro

Comment: Muchas gracias! :DD